# Shopify - Display all the images from collection list

Tags: javascript, html, shopify, liquid

what i would like to do is display all the pictures from my collection list.

```
{% for collection in collections %}
      {% if collection.title == "OMBRONE COLLECTION" %}

        <a href="{{collection.url}}">
          
         

           <! -- If the collection title  == 'collection title I provide' 
i would like to display the products pictures in that collection.

' -->
          
          
          
          
        <div class="cm_colec_title"><span>{{collection.title}}</span></div>
        </a>
   
     {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

If the collection title  == 'collection title I provide'
i would like to display the products pictures in that collection.

Comment: need to use like this to get the products for this particluar colection `{% assign products = collection['collection_handle'].products %}` into `if` condition.

Comment: I'm still having a problem so is it going to be something like this ?
```
{% for collection in collections %}
      {% if collection.title == "OMBRONE COLLECTION" %}

        <a href="{{collection.url}}">
          
         
      {% assign products = collection['collection_handle'].products %}
      {% if products.image %}
            <img src="{{ products | img_url: '450x450' }}"/>
      {% else %}
            
      {% endif %}<div class="cm_colec_title"><span>{{collection.title}}</span></div>
        </a>
   
     {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `collection['collection_handle'].products`  here `collection_handle` is the url slug of your actual collection like `OMBRONE COLLECTION` is the name collection and slug is the end part into URL bar when navigate to this collection like test.com/collection/test

Comment: use something like this [Link](https://gist.github.com/o-nkar/56676c2e4dfe6d12173afaa7c5fb069b) might need some changes according to your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. I just put a comment in the github can you check there please ?

Comment: simple use like it `{% assign products = collection.products %}`

Comment: try like this `{{ product.images[0] | img_url:'300x' | img_tag }}`

Comment: `{{ product.images[0].src | img_url:'300x' | img_tag }}`